# Power BI: How to pull in a column to an IF statement

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure that says (basically) if the value in a column doesn't exists, display "No", otherwise display the column.  Currently, I can't get this to pull in the column.  This is essentially what I'm trying to accomplish

```
Status = IF(Table[Column] = BLANK(), "No", Table[Column])
```

Currently, the only thing I can get to work is this:

```
Status = IF(CALCULATE(COUNTA(Table[Column])) = BLANK(), "No", "Yes")
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a report you are trying to build with this measure?

Comment: Can you please give a sample output .

Comment: When the data is null, your measure should work, i believe there is something wrong with your data. Like there is a space?